# Nested loops, how many times run and complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, nested-loops, code-complexity

I have these 2 codes, the question is to find how many times x=x+1 will run in each occasion as T1(n) stands for code 1 and T2(n) stands for code 2. Then I have to find the BIG O of each one, but I know how to do it, the thing is I get stuck in finding how many times ( as to n of course ) will x = x + 1 will run.

CODE 1:

```
for( i= 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    for(j = 1; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
          {
           for( k = 1; k <= n - j + 1; k++)
               {
               x = x + 1;
               }
          }
    }
```

CODE 2:

```
for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
   {
    h = n;
    while(h > 0)
        {
        for (i = 1; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
            {
            x = x+1;
            } 
        h = h/2;
        }

   }
```

I am really stuck, and have read already a lot so I ask if someone can help me, please explain me analytically.

PS: I think in the code 2 , this `for (i = 1; i <= sqrt(n); i++)` will run n*log(n) times, right? Then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `code 1` you have that the number of calls of `x=x+1` is:

[image]

Here we bounded `1+sqrt(2)+...+sqrt(n)` with `n sqrt(n)` and used the fact that the first term is the leading term.

For `code 2` the calculations are simpler:

[image]
[image]

The second loop actually goes from `h=n` to `0` by iterating `h = h/2` but you can see that this is the same as going from `1` to `log n`. What we used is the fact the `j, t, i` are mutually independent (analogously just like we can  write that sum from `1` to `n` of `f(n)` is just `nf(n)`).

Comment: I forgot to say that in code 2, n = 2^k where k is an integer. If it's not the same.

Comment: @PavTze doesn't matter the result is the same

Comment: @PavTze acutally you could right `O(n sqrt(n) k)` instead which is the same as above but a simplified version. Which to use is a preference.

Comment: I know this will get hard for you, but can you please explain me the math part as of arithmetic series and sum from the above? I haven't understand the second equation.

Comment: @PavTze which part exactly? the second equation? did you manage to understand the first?

Comment: I edited my comment. Yeap the second equation, I understand anything else. You used this right? 

   http://www.purplemath.com/modules/series4.htm ( the first formula, right? )

Comment: @PavTze for the first formula I used the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) that `1+2+...+p = p(p+1)/2`, `p =sqrt(i)`. for the second just independence. check the updated answer.

Comment: I haven't understand in the second equation in CODE 1 answer what you have done. I mean what did you do at the sum which have (n-j+1) so that it got [sqrt(i)(n+1) -  ( sqrt(i) (sqrt(i)+1) )/2.

Comment: @PavTze [this](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7Bi%7D%7D%20%28n-j&plus;1%29%20%3D%20%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7Bi%7D%7D%28n&plus;1%29%20-%20%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7Bi%7D%7Dj%20%3D%20%5Csqrt%7Bi%7D%28n&plus;1%29-%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7Bi%7D%28%5Csqrt%7Bi%7D%20&plus;%201%29%7D%7B2%7D)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I think I understood it. At the last equation where you get the big O, you did for each some from i = 1 to n for example, n/2(a(0) - a(n)) ?

Comment: @PavTze I explain with the next sentence "Here we bounded `1+sqrt(2)+...+sqrt(n) `with `n sqrt(n)  `and used the fact that the first term(`n * (1+sqrt(2)+...+sqrt(n) `) is the leading term"

Comment: I see I understand, so for the others two also ,we have at the end n^2 * sqrt(n) - n * ( n/2 ) + n * sqrt(n)/2 right? And the first term as you said is the leading and what we need about the Big O. Tell me I am right, it's a bit confusing at start :P

Comment: Well, you saved me hours to say the least. Grazie :)

Comment: @PavTze that's why I'm here - to help :)

Comment: oh my god, I did a terrible mistake, at the first code it is                            for(j = 1; j <= sqrt(n); j++) instead of sqrt(i). Will it be a problem to our solution ( as long as I make the exact changes )?

Comment: @PavTze it would definitely be easier. try it as a practice problem